# Laravel migration not showing in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, laravel

[[image: Picture 1][1][image: Picture 2]

I have done a php artisan migration but nothing appeard in the database please find a fix that works.As you can see string('address')

Comment: Have you actually ran the migration using `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: may be you have migrated this before adding those two fields.

Comment: Please refrain from using images, instead of code. Here is a [list of reasons why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3578036).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the OP is confusing [migrations](https://laravel.com/8.x/migrations) with [seeding](https://laravel.com/8.x/migrations). The table clearly exists, it is just devoid of data. Either that, or they don't understand that if the table is empty, then PHPMyAdmin will show this screen, if they need to see the table structure, then they will need to run `describe profiles`.

Answer (score 1):

You ran migrate earlier, correct? If yes, you can run:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

This will drop existing tables and data and create a new structure.

Or, if you want to add new fields without losing existing data, you should add a new migration. In that case, the command should be the following.

```
php artisan make:migration add_new_field_name_in_table_name --table=table_name
```

Comment: I did php artisan migrate:fresh.

Comment: Has your `address` field appeared? @chenas

Answer (score 0):

The migration looks fine, like any migration. Did the console output display that the migration was processed?

```sh
Migrating: 2021_06_09_102328_create_profiles_table
Migrated:  2021_06_09_102328_create_profiles_table
```

If so, it might be a good idea to check the values in your `.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql #EXPECTED
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 #EXPECTED
DB_PORT=3306 #EXPECTED
DB_DATABASE={DB_NAME} #YOUR DB NAME
DB_USERNAME={DB_USERNAME} #YOUR DB USERNAME
DB_PASSWORD={DB_PASSWORD} #YOUR DB PASSWORD
```

And ensure they are the same as the values that you use to connect to phpmyadmin.